# Share tycho build results between computers

Tags: maven, nexus, tycho

I've successfully built Core module with tycho and deployed it to Nexus using "maven clean deploy" command. Now I want to use this Core module artifacts to build my Live module (placed on other PC), but tycho can not see this Core module using manifest-based approach.

Core module build artifacts are placed on Nexus (standard, not p2 format).
It works if Core and Live share the same local .m2/repository folder, but it does not work in case of sharing using Nexus.

Is it possible to share build artifacts without creating new p2 repo and without using standard maven based dependency management approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Nexus_Unzip_Plugin. This Nexus plugin enables binary p2 artifact exchange between projects via Nexus using standard `maven2` format repositories. You don't need to create repositories with format `p2` in your Nexus if you use this plugin.